# what does *line mean in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently doing HackerRank and one of the levels has this code:

```
grade_book = {}
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
```

I'm not sure what the *line does in this example. The program is supposed to take a number of students, a name, and a list of scores which it then stores in a dictionary. The final input is the name that will return that students average scores.

Comment: Why don't you try to `print(name, line)` after this line and find out for yourself ? ;)

Comment: ah ok i didnt realize i could print it